# Jquery Tmpl If Statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I'm using jquery tmpl plugin. The idea is to add a class to an img tag if the statement is false.

Here's the template code:

```
<img src="/assets/${assetId}/graphic.jpg" {{ if complete != true }} class="incomplete" {{ /if }}>
```

And here's the result on a browser (mozilla):

```
<img class="incomplete" }}="" !="true" complete="" if="" {{="" src="/assets/821/graphic.jpg">
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Lose the spaces: `{{if complete != true}}...{{/if}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. It was just to remove the spaces on the statements.

Before:

```
<img src="/assets/${asset[enter link description here][1]Id}/graphic.jpg" {{ if complete != true }} class="incomplete" {{ /if }}>
```

Fixed:

```
<img src="/assets/${assetId}/graphic.jpg" {{if complete != true}} class="incomplete" {{/if}}>
```

Credit goes to DCoder.